# array_chunk and send all parts in foreach loop not working

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, numbers

i have an array of mobile numbers with more than 2000 item:

```
$mobiles = array("number 1, number 2, number 3, ...)
```

i wanna to split this array to 100 segments and then do perform in each array:
see my code:

```
$username='xxxxxxx';
    $password='xxxxxx';
    $sendNumber='1000100';
    $message= 'text text';
    $client=new SoapClient("http://example.com/services/smsService.svc?wsdl");
    //spilit mobile number to 100 segments
    $spilited_mobiles = array_chunk($mobiles,100,true);
    foreach ($spilited_mobiles as $numbers){
        $params=array('username'=>$username,'password'=>$password,
    'senderNumber'=>$sendNumber,'recipientNumbers'=>$numbers,'message'=>$message,'saveType'=>1);
    $result=$client->sendMessage($params);
    }
```

the problem is it just send for first 100 number and other numbers in loop not performed
thank you

Comment: Try `var_dump($spilited_mobiles)` and see what the array holds.

Comment: Make sure you have errors enabled and displayed, it may be failing with something silently which ends the loop.  I also would make sure your data isn't actually defined as `array("number 1, number 2` - each number should be in quotes - `array("number 1", "number 2"...` otherwise they are all 1 element of the array.

Comment: @Joe: stick to using one account please; if you want to edit this question do it with the account that you asked it with. Multiple accounts are permitted only if those accounts don’t do things you couldn’t do with a single account.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add another `foreach` to loop the 100.

This `$numbers` is an array which contains 100 mobile numbers.

```
'recipientNumbers'=>$numbers
```

**Solution**

```
$spilited_mobiles = array_chunk($mobiles, 100, TRUE);
foreach ($spilited_mobiles as $numbers){

    //Loop the 100
    foreach($numbers as $number){
            $params=array('username'=>$username,'password'=>$password,
            'senderNumber'=>$sendNumber,'recipientNumbers'=>$number,'message'=>$message,'saveType'=>1);
            $result=$client->sendMessage($params);
    }
}
```

You can try the sample code [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a05452074ebe4f9397c6d8072f5cd2a745b4c56c)

Comment: thank you.Edit: i forget to mention that recipientNumbers'=>$number in $params hold an array of numbers not just a number

Answer (score 0):

**You need to add two foreach for do that action:**

```
$mobiles = array(12, 123, 1234);
$username='xxxxxxx';
$password='xxxxxx';
$sendNumber='1000100';
$message= 'text text';
$client=new SoapClient("http://example.com/services/smsService.svc?wsdl");
$spilited_mobiles = array_chunk($mobiles,100,true);
foreach ($spilited_mobiles as $numbers){
  foreach($numbers as $number){
    $params=array('username'=>$username,'password'=>$password,
    'senderNumber'=>$sendNumber,'recipientNumbers'=>$number,'message'=>$message,'saveType'=>1);
    $result=$client->sendMessage($params);
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you. Edit: i forget to mention that recipientNumbers'=>$number in $params hold an array of numbers not just a number

Comment: foreach(array_chunk($spilited_mobiles, 100) as $numbers){
        $params=array('username'=>$username,'password'=>$password,
    'senderNumber'=>$sendNumber,'recipientNumbers'=>$numbers,'message'=>$message,'saveType'=>1);
    $result=$client->sendMessage($params);
    }

Comment: not working. that's make extra array and not work at all. in my code, with var_dump in foreach i know it have correct arrays. but foreach loop not work and just work in first chunked array. maybe it is a bug in http://example.com/services/smsService.svc?wsdl that can not handel multi request at time